# Firefox - modified setting in omni.ja not reflected

Tags: firefox

I've modified an `accesskey` in **omni.ja** in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox` in

```
chrome\en-US\locale\browser\browser.dtd
```

from:

```
<!ENTITY openLinkCmd.accesskey "W">
```

to:

```
<!ENTITY openLinkCmd.accesskey "V">
```

Repacked omni.ja, restarted, even rebooted the machine but the change is not reflected. What am I douing wrong? Is it hardcoded for English version? Firefox 12.0.

Comment: from <!ENTITY openLinkCmd.accesskey        "W"> to <!ENTITY openLinkCmd.accesskey        "V">

Answer (score 1):

You should `disable/enalbe` at least one `add-on` to reload `omni.ja`.
(I've wasted several hours debugging this problem.)

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to reload `omni.ja` is to start firefox with the `--purgecaches` option. Other suggestions did not work for me, while `firefox --purgecaches` reloaded omni.ja and applied my changes.

See also: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=3025663

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to change the access key of "copy Link" in the context menu from "a" to "e". I modified `chrome\en-US\locale\browser\browser.dtd`, it didn't work.

After removing [Menu Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/), it worked. So check if there are similar add-ons and disable them if necessary.